# Why is my MONTH view still showing a DAY as the title?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

UPDATE: I see the issue was not fixed in the current release so am especially interested in any suggestions for workarounds. For example, maybe I could hide the default header with CSS and add the correct title in the view.

ORIGINAL QUESTION: I know this was [a bug in the 7.x-2.x-dev version of the Date module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2294973), but it seems to have been patched. I am running 7.x-2.8 (the latest) in which it should be fixed.

Why am I having this problem, and more importantly how can I work around it? I am working on a site where I only have access to the site administration, and not the server (ie: I can't patch the module myself).

[image: screenshot of month view]

Comment: How do you tell it's supposed to be fixed if all patch files apparently failed testing? Also, if you can't patch, why bother asking? It is how it is, it'll change when it'll change, why bother if you're helpless anyway? Unless your GUI allows module uploads. If so, you can patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the fix isn't in the latest release (7.x-2.8) yet and is instead in the current (7.x-2.x-dev) version. According to the comment #70 in that thread you posted, the patch is meant to be applied to the current release and not the latest dev (which is why it failed). If you run the patch in comment 70 against your 7.x-2.8 version it should correct the issue. As you stated that isn't an option, you can try to have the drupal update page grab the latest dev.

You can always check the release date for different branches on the project page. For example, [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) currently shows the 7.x-2.8 branch as having been released on July 29th, 2014 while the latest commit, 7.x-2.x-dev, was released on June 16th, 2014. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, I had assumed that because they closed the issue that it had been fixed in that release. My bad.